# calculate sum of a column based on another col

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My df looks like this:

```
value    type
12       x
34       z
54       x
14       y
```

I want to create a new column `df.sum` where I want to do a sum of the value col but only where the `type == x`. The remaining rows should be empty. So for example, the output should be like this:

```
value    type    sum
12       x       86
34       z
54       x       86
14       y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle a single type (only `x`):

```
mask = df['type'].eq('x')
df.loc[mask, 'sum'] = df.loc[mask, 'value'].sum()
```

if you might need to handle several:

```
types = ['x'] # add others, e.g.: types = ['x', 'y']
df.loc[df['type'].isin(types), 'sum'] = (df.groupby('type')['value']
                                           .transform('sum')
                                         )
```

output:

```
   value type   sum
0     12    x  66.0
1     34    z   NaN
2     54    x  66.0
3     14    y   NaN
```

Comment: does df.loc automatically make changes to the df or do we need to reassign to a ```df```

Comment: as used here it is already an assignment (left part of the `=`), so it modifies the original `df` ;)

Comment: Can I use the same format with a ```count()``` function instead of sum() too? For example if I want to calculate the total "number of values" where the respective type matches

Answer (score 0):

yeah it looks oddish but still works:

```
types = ['2','x']  # your keys to sum

df = df.merge(df.query('type in @types').
              groupby('type', as_index=False).
              agg(sum), 
              how='left', on='type', suffixes=(None,'_sum'))
'''
   value type  value_sum
0     12    x       66.0
1     34    z        NaN
2     54    x       66.0
3     14    y        NaN
```